# Is there a way to tell SimpleXMLElement to put the new child on a new line?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Is there a way to tell SimpleXMLElement to put the new child on a new line?

I'm appending a single line on the end of an existing XML file.  The file looks like this:

```
<markers>
<marker id="2" name="Diane Gold, CORPORATE TAI CHI means do it in a group." address="Boca Raton, FL 33432, USA" lat="26.340200" lng="-80.081400" type="school"/>
<marker id="3" name="Tai Chi - Stress Management and Relaxation Technology" address="10100 Roe Ave, Overland Park, KS 66207, USA" lat="38.945300" lng="-94.639400" type="school"/>
<marker id="4" name="Wise Orchid Taijiquan and QiGong" address="2002 E Union St, Seattle, WA 98122, USA" lat="47.613200" lng="-122.306000" type="school"/>
</marker>
```

I'm using a function I created that looks like this to add a single line to the end of the file:

```
    $xmlstr=file_get_contents('my_filename.xml');
    $address=get_address_string($event['eventtag'],'eventtag','events');
    echo($xmlstr);
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
    $marker = $sxe->addChild('marker');
    $marker->addAttribute('id', $event['eventid']);
    $marker->addAttribute('name', $event['eventname']);
    $marker->addAttribute('address', $address);
    $marker->addAttribute('lat', $event['latitude_dd']);
    $marker->addAttribute('lng', $event['longitude_dd']);
    $marker->addAttribute('type', 'event');
    echo $sxe->asXML('my_filename.xml');
}
```

The problem is that it adds the new element without any line breaks:

```
<marker id="" name="Newest Event for Testing" address="1 Arrowhead Drive, , Douglassville, PA, 19518  USA" lat="" lng="" type="event"/><marker id="" name="Newest Event for Testing" address="1 Arrowhead Drive, , Douglassville, PA, 19518  USA" lat="" lng="" type="event"/><marker id="" name="Kutztown University World Tai Chi Day 2020" address="1 Arrowhead Drive, , Douglassville, PA, 19518  USA" lat="" lng="" type="event"/><marker id="1299" name="A Newer WTCD test event" address="1 Arrowhead Drive, , Douglassville, PA, 19518  USA" lat="" lng="" type="event"/><marker id="1302" name="Newest Event for Testin2" address="1 Arrowhead Drive, , Douglassville, PA, 19518  USA" lat="" lng="" type="event"/></markers>
```

I've tried dozens of different things, and I've read everything on stackoverflow that I could find on the topic of new lines.  Most deal with formatting of the file after it's been read in, or uses DOM or  something other than SimpleXMLElement to write to the xml.  I'm just learning this stuff, and have exhausted my knowledge in how to get a line break in there.  Does anyone have any clue as to what else I can try?

Thanks
CJ

Comment: No, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. Whitespace between tags is irrelevant in XML, and `SimpleXML` doesn't have any way to customize the formatting.

Comment: Neither does the more complex `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @Barmar Depends of the format. Whitespaces can have meaning. Take `pre` in XHTML for example.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleXML does not allow to control the formatting. It is not relevant for basic XML data.

It is possible with DOM if you understand that anything is a node. Not just elements, but attributes and texts as well.

The last child node of `markers` is not a `marker` element, but a
text node with whitespaces following it.

Here is a small demo:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$markers = $document->documentElement;
foreach ($markers->childNodes as $childNode) {
    echo $childNode->nodeName, ': ', strlen($childNode->textContent), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
#text: 1
marker: 0
#text: 1
marker: 0
#text: 1
marker: 0
#text: 1
```

As you can see in the output the `marker` element nodes are surrounded by text nodes with a single character - the line break.

The formatting are text nodes with white space characters. You can create and append/insert them as needed.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$markers = $document->documentElement;

$marker = $markers->appendChild($document->createElement('marker'));
$marker->setAttribute('id', '42');
$marker->setAttribute('name', 'A Title');
// add the line break as a text node
$markers->appendChild($document->createTextNode("\n"));

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers>
<marker id="2" name="Diane Gold, CORPORATE TAI CHI means do it in a group." address="Boca Raton, FL 33432, USA" lat="26.340200" lng="-80.081400" type="school"/>
<marker id="3" name="Tai Chi - Stress Management and Relaxation Technology" address="10100 Roe Ave, Overland Park, KS 66207, USA" lat="38.945300" lng="-94.639400" type="school"/>
<marker id="4" name="Wise Orchid Taijiquan and QiGong" address="2002 E Union St, Seattle, WA 98122, USA" lat="47.613200" lng="-122.306000" type="school"/>
<marker id="42" name="A Title"/>
</markers>
```

Additionally DOM supports automatic formatting. If used it will add whitespaces during the serialization.